# How do I modify my display function to accept floating-point numbers via the stack?

Tags: assembly, x86, floating-point, clang, x86-64

I am trying to print a floating-point number with x86_64 assembly on MacOS using Clang, with Intel syntax: `clang -masm=intel float.asm`. I was told that I should pass a floating-point argument through the `xmm0` register. Also, I am now relying on popping and pushing an arbitrary register, `rbx` to align the call stack. However, my code is still giving me a segmentation fault. GDB told me that the `movaps` instruction was my point of error:

```
(gdb) disassemble
Dump of assembler code for function main:
=> 0x0000000100003f78 <+0>: movaps 0x4095(%rip),%xmm0        # 0x100008014 <pi>
   0x0000000100003f7f <+7>: pop    %rbx
   0x0000000100003f80 <+8>: callq  0x100003f66 <display>
   0x0000000100003f85 <+13>:    push   %rbx
   0x0000000100003f86 <+14>:    mov    $0x0,%rdi
   0x0000000100003f8d <+21>:    mov    $0x2000001,%rax
   0x0000000100003f94 <+28>:    syscall
End of assembler dump.
```

What am I doing wrong in passing a double to `xmm0` to `movaps`? I am not too familiar with `x86` so a thorough explanation would be helpful.

```
    .global _main
    .extern _printf

    .data
format_number:
    .asciz "%f\n"
pi:
    .double 3.14

    .text
display:
    lea rdi, format_number [rip]
    xor rax, rax
    pop rbx
    call _printf
    push rbx
    ret


_main:
    movaps xmm0, [pi + rip]
    pop rbx
    call display
    push rbx
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rax, 0x2000001
    syscall
```

Comment: It's not truncated by the printing, it's already truncated by the assembler for the push. My version of gnu assembler on linux even produces an error message for that _"Error: junk `.4' after expression"_. Are you sure you are not reusing the object from a previous successful build which only had an integer? In any case, you use %d format which only prints integers.

Comment: Note the `;` proceeds even if the compilation fails. You might want to use something like `gcc -masm=intel float.asm && echo Compiled ok && ./a.out`

Comment: There's no reason to use the stack for passing args in the first place vs. passing in RDI or XMM0 like the standard calling convention.  If all your functions only take a small fixed number of args, that's no harder to implement and doesn't conflict with using the stack for your VM / language's stack.

Comment: @Jester: Note that `gcc -masm=intel foo.asm` on MacOS actually feeds it to clang as an assembler, not GNU GAS.  It seems that clang unfortunately doesn't error on that syntax, and also doesn't assemble that immediate to a float bit-pattern.  Wow, I checked on Linux and not even a warning with clang 10, just assembles to `6a 1a 
  push  26`

Comment: @Jester I checked and I was rebuilding successfully each time. I also changed `format_number` to `"%f"` but now it only gives me `0.000000`. My solution might not work from a foundational standpoint; do you know where to find a good resource to make this work?

Comment: `printf` expects the value in `xmm0` as a double if you use `%f`.

Comment: ... and if you did load into `xmm0` instead of `esi`, that `26` you pushed would be the bit-pattern for a tiny subnormal `double` that would print as 0.0 anyway, unless you used `%g`.  You need to pass a `double` (IEEE binary64) bit-pattern.  There's no good way to write a double bit-pattern as an immediate in GAS / clang intel syntax, AFAIK.  You could manually encode it yourself (http://weitz.de/ieee/) and `mov rdi, 0x403a666666666666` (but you can't `push 0x403a666666666666` directly because it doesn't fit in a 32-bit sign-extended immediate).

Comment: @PeterCordes I updated my question by the way.

Comment: @Jester I updated my question

Comment: `movaps` is a 16-byte alignment-required load.  For one double you want `movsd`.  Look at compiler output.  This could easily have been answered by checking how a compiler compiles `printf("%f", 3.14)` or whatever, and looking up the instructions it used in the manual to see what they do if you weren't sure.

Comment: Oh BTW, your `pop rbx` *before* a call (to load the return address?) looks super broken because your `display` function clobbers RBX.  So it looks like main's return address will get replaced with `display`'s return address.  The only reason this doesn't totally fail is that you unwisely make an exit system call instead of returning from main.  (stdout can be full-buffered when you redirect to a file, and exiting that way won't flush IO buffers.)